# valueChangeListener in JSF 1.1 not working

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-1.2

I m working on JSF 1.1 , and I want to create Radio button event with immediate result on change.

I created this stuff:

```
<h:panelGrid>
    <h:selectOneRadio 
          value="#{ReservationHelperBean.listReservationForDailyViewRadio}" 
          valueChangeListener="#{ReservationHelperBean.onLoadReservations}" onchange="submit()" 
          immediate="true">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="Red" itemLabel="Color1 - Red" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="Green" itemLabel="Color1 - Green" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="Blue" itemLabel="Color1 - Blue" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

And method in the bean, that handles the `ValueChangeEvent` is:

```
public void loadReservations(final ValueChangeEvent evt){
    String reserCriteria = (String)evt.getNewValue();
    System.out.println("<><><><><><><><>< "+reserCriteria);
    setListReservationForDailyViewRadio(reserCriteria);
}
```

but it's not working.
after radio click am getting this error_

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.azureworlds.beans.pms.helper.ReservationHelperBean.onLoadReservations(javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent)
```

Is any one now where am going wrong?

**Ans**
when i cut that listener and re paste in it, its working (calling back end)

Comment: I guess it failed on the `Process validations` JSF phase. Place somewhere on the page `<h:messages />` and see what the error(s) may be.

Comment: @kocko after adding onchange="submit()" am getting error like _NoSuchMethodException_ ..

Comment: Search for `onLoadReservations` in your code - probably a typo somewhere

Comment: Make sure you method signature matches `public void onLoadReservations(javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent event)`.

Comment: yes,its there in bean_
public void onLoadReservations(final ValueChangeEvent evt)

Comment: Really? The code in your question which you apparently copypasted from your real code shows a different method name, without the `on` prefix.

Comment: May be i was wrong or wrongly copy pasted, but i wasn't changed anything.i did redo n restarted IDE -Myeclipse n changed it again as same.